# How can I change XAMPP DocumentRoot with a bash command?

Tags: bash, xampp

Changing XAMPP DocumentRoot is hard! I should open
`/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf`
then find

```
DocumentRoot "/home/ehcan/Desktop/Company1/Project1"
<Directory "/home/ehcan/Desktop/Company1/Project1">
```

then change it to another project.
it's very time consuming.

So what I need is a simple bash file for function, so I can `cd` to desired directory like

```
/home/ehcan/Desktop/Company2/Project5
```

and type something like `sudo xampp-here`,

then command will do:

edit httpd.conf -> XAMPP restart

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out for myself.
I have some aliases and function in my `~/.bashrc` file.
i can run:

`xampp-start`: Start XAMPP

`xampp-stop`: Stop XAMPP

`xampp-restart`: Restart XAMPP

**AND** `xampp-here` in any directory to change `/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf` file and restart XAMPP.

```
alias xampp-start="sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start"
alias xampp-stop="sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop"
alias xampp-restart="sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart"
xampp-here() {
    curDir=$(pwd)
    sudo sed -i "/DocumentRoot \".*/c\DocumentRoot \"$curDir\"" /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf
    sudo sed -i "/\<Directory \".*/c\ \<Directory \"$curDir\"\>" /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf
    xampp-restart
}
```